# register ErrorCollector or intercept parse errors for wire format?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

When It is possible to define a custom [`ErrorCollector`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.tokenizer#ErrorCollector) class for handling `google::protobuf` parsing errors

```
struct ErrorCollector : ::google::protobuf::io::ErrorCollector
{
    void AddError(int line, int column, const std::string& message) override
    {
        // log error
    }
    void AddWarning(int line, int column, const std::string& message) override
    {
        // log warning
    }
};
```

When parsing from a text file, you can use the protobuf `TextFormat` class and register your custom `ErrorCollector`

```
::google::protobuf::io::IstreamInputStream input_stream(&file);
::google::protobuf::TextFormat::Parser parser;

ErrorCollector error_collector;
parser.RecordErrorsTo(&error_collector);

if (parser.Parse(&input_stream, &msg))
{
    // handle msg
}
```

For parsing wire format, I currently use `Message::ParseFromArray`

```
if (msg.ParseFromArray(data, data_len))
{
    // handle msg
}
```

This doesn't allow me to specify a custom `ErrorCollector` though.

I've searched through the [source code](https://github.com/google/protobuf/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=recorderrorsto), but as of yet have been unable to find if this is possible.

- **Is it possible to use an `ErrorCollector` when parsing wire format?**
- **Is there another way to intercept parse errors and make them available to client code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are essentially two ways that parsing the wire format could fail:

1. The bytes are not a valid protobuf (e.g. they are corrupted, or in a totally different format).
2. A required field is missing.

For case 1, protobuf does not give you any more information than "it's invalid". This is partly for code simplicity (and speed), but it is also partly because any attempt to provide more information usually turns out more misleading than helpful. Detailed error reporting is useful for text format because text is often written by humans, but machines make very different kinds of errors. In some languages, protobuf actually reports specific errors like "end-group tag does not match start-group tag". In the vast majority of cases, this error really just means "the bytes are corrupted", but inevitably people think the error is trying to tell them something deeper which they do not understand. They then post questions to stack overflow like "How do I make sure my start-group and end-group tags match?" when they really should be comparing bytes between their source and destination to narrow down where they got corrupted. Even reporting the byte position where the parse error occurred is not very useful: protobuf is a dense encoding, which means that many random corrupt byte sequences will parse successfully, which means the parser may only notice a problem somewhere later down the line rather than at the point where things actually went wrong.

The one case that clearly *is* useful to distinguish is case 2 (missing required fields) -- at least, if you use required fields ([I personally recommend avoiding them](https://capnproto.org/faq.html#how-do-i-make-a-field-required-like-in-protocol-buffers)). There are a couple options here:

- Normally, required field checks write errors to the console (on stderr). You can intercept these and record them your own way using [`SetLogHandler`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.common#SetLogHandler.details), but this doesn't give you structured information, only text messages.
- To check required fields more programmatically, you can separate required field checking from parsing. Use `MessageLite::ParsePartialFromArray()` or one of the other `Partial` parsing methods to parse a message while ignoring the absence of required fields. You can then use the `MessageLite::IsInitialized()` to check if all required fields are set. If it returns false, use [`Message::FindInitializationErrors()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message.FindInitializationErrors.details) to get a list of paths of all required fields that are missing.